# Need advice on how to pass an array of instances to another array

Tags: java, arrays, jpanel, parameter-passing

First off Im still in the process of learning and appreciate all the help I have received on here. I am creating a program that a customer can que up multiple sandwich orders. right now the program is very basic but works for placing one order. I will fill it out with more items once everything is up and running. I want to pass my sub array to an order array to hold the multiple sandwiches then once the whole order is complete I will print out a grand total. Im also not sure how I will go about looping the program to place multiple orders but I feel like this should be done in the order class unless there is an easier way to do it all in the main. Any advice or pointers is appreciated. I will update as I continue to work on it.

```
import com.sun.corba.se.impl.ior.OldJIDLObjectKeyTemplate;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SubwayMobileOrder
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new TabletScreen();
    frame.setTitle("Subway Order App");
    frame.setSize(800, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
}

class TabletScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

// Customer name
private JLabel jlbCustomerName = new JLabel("Enter a Name for the order:");
private JTextField jtfCustomerName = new JTextField(15);

// Bread choices
private JLabel jlbBread = new JLabel("Choose a type of bread");
private JComboBox jcbBreadType = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"Select Bread Type", "Italin Herbs and Cheese", "Wheat"});

// Sub Size
private JLabel jlbSize = new JLabel("What size sub would you like");
private JComboBox jcbSize = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"Select Sub Size", "12 inch", "6 inch"});

// Sub meat
private JLabel jlbMeat = new JLabel("Select what Meat(s) you would like");
private JCheckBox jcxChicken = new JCheckBox("Chicken");
private JCheckBox jcxBacon = new JCheckBox("Bacon");

// Sub Cheese
private JLabel jlbCheese = new JLabel("Select what Cheese(s) you would like");
private JCheckBox jcxAmerican = new JCheckBox("American");
private JCheckBox jcxSwiss = new JCheckBox("Swiss");

// Ingrediants ie veggies and what not
private JLabel jlbVeggies = new JLabel("Select what Veggies you would like");
private JCheckBox jcxOnion = new JCheckBox("Onion");
private JCheckBox jcxLettuce = new JCheckBox("Lettuce");

// Addons
private JLabel jlbDoubleCheese = new JLabel("Double Cheese");
private JComboBox jcbDoubleCheese = new JComboBox(new Object[] {"yes", "no"});


private JLabel jlbDoubleMeat = new JLabel("Double Meat");
private JComboBox jcbDoubleMeat = new JComboBox(new Object[] {"yes", "no"});

// Ok button
JButton okButton = new JButton("Sub Complete");


public TabletScreen() {

    // Main panel with: name, bread type, size
    JPanel mainOrderInfo = new JPanel();
    mainOrderInfo.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1, 10, 10));
    mainOrderInfo.add(jlbCustomerName);
    mainOrderInfo.add(jtfCustomerName);
    mainOrderInfo.add(jlbBread);
    mainOrderInfo.add(jcbBreadType);
    mainOrderInfo.add(jlbSize);
    mainOrderInfo.add(jcbSize);

    // Meat Panel
    JPanel meatPanel = new JPanel();
    meatPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 10, 10));
    meatPanel.add(jlbMeat);
    meatPanel.add(jcxBacon);
    meatPanel.add(jcxChicken);

    // Cheese Panel
    JPanel cheesePanel = new JPanel();
    cheesePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 10, 10));
    cheesePanel.add(jlbCheese);
    cheesePanel.add(jcxAmerican);
    cheesePanel.add(jcxSwiss);

    // Veggies Panel
    JPanel veggiesPanel = new JPanel();
    veggiesPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 10, 10));
    veggiesPanel.add(jlbVeggies);
    veggiesPanel.add(jcxOnion);
    veggiesPanel.add(jcxLettuce);

    // Addons Panel
    JPanel addonsPanel = new JPanel();
    addonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 10, 10));
    addonsPanel.add(jlbDoubleCheese);
    addonsPanel.add(jcbDoubleCheese);
    addonsPanel.add(jlbDoubleMeat);
    addonsPanel.add(jcbDoubleMeat);

    // Setup overall main panel
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 5, 15, 15));
    mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    mainPanel.setOpaque(true);
    mainPanel.add(mainOrderInfo);
    mainPanel.add(meatPanel);
    mainPanel.add(cheesePanel);
    mainPanel.add(veggiesPanel);
    mainPanel.add(addonsPanel);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 10, 10));
    buttonPanel.add(okButton);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    okButton.addActionListener(this);

    }


//------------------------------------------------------------------------\\

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        Sandwich sub = new Sandwich();

        // getting bread
        if (jcbBreadType.getSelectedIndex() == 1)
         { sub.addIngredients(new ItlainHerbs()); }
        if (jcbBreadType.getSelectedIndex() == 2)
            { sub.addIngredients(new Wheat()); }

        // getting meat
        if (jcxBacon.isSelected())
            { sub.addIngredients(new Bacon()); }
        if (jcxChicken.isSelected())
            { sub.addIngredients(new Chicken()); }

        // getting cheese
        if (jcxAmerican.isSelected())
            { sub.addIngredients(new American()); }
        if (jcxSwiss.isSelected())
            { sub.addIngredients(new Swiss()); }

        // getting veggies
        if (jcxOnion.isSelected())
            { sub.addIngredients(new Onion()); }
        if (jcxLettuce.isSelected())
            { sub.addIngredients(new Lettuce()); }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sub.toString());

    }



}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\

class Order
{
    private static List<Items> order = new List<Order>(15);

    public Order() {}
}

class Sandwich
{
    private static ArrayList<Ingredients> ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredients>(20);

    public Sandwich() {}

    public static void addIngredients(Ingredients x) { ingredients.add(x); }


public String toString()
{
    String yourOrder = "\n Your order is as follows: \n ";
    for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.size(); i++)
    {
        if (ingredients.get(i) instanceof Bread)
            { yourOrder += "\nBread type: " + ingredients.get(i); }
        if (ingredients.get(i) instanceof Meat)
            { yourOrder += "\nMeat type: " + ingredients.get(i); }
        if (ingredients.get(i) instanceof Cheese)
            { yourOrder += "\nCheese type: " + ingredients.get(i); }
        if (ingredients.get(i) instanceof Veggies)
            { yourOrder += "\nVeggie type: " + ingredients.get(i); }

    }

    return yourOrder;
}
}

//===============================================================\\

class Ingredients // Ingredients super class
{
    Ingredients() {}
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------\\
class Bread extends Ingredients
{
    String bread;
    Bread(String bread) { this.bread = bread; }

    public String toString() { return bread; }
}

class ItlainHerbs extends Bread
{
    ItlainHerbs() { super("Italin Herbs and Cheese"); }
}

class Wheat extends Bread
{
    Wheat() { super("Wheat"); }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------\\

class Meat extends Ingredients
{
    String meat;
    Meat(String meat) { this.meat = meat; }

    public String toString() { return meat; }
}

class Bacon extends Meat
{
    Bacon() { super("Bacon"); }
}

class Chicken extends Meat
{
    Chicken() { super("Chiken"); }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------\\
class Cheese extends Ingredients
{
    String cheese;
    Cheese(String cheese) { this.cheese = cheese; }

    public String toString() { return cheese; }
}

class American extends Cheese
{
    American() { super("American"); }
}

class Swiss extends Cheese
{
    Swiss() { super("Swiss"); }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------\\
class Veggies extends Ingredients
{
    String veggies;
    Veggies(String veggies) { this.veggies = veggies; }

    public String toString() { return veggies; }
}

class Onion extends Veggies
{
    Onion() { super("Onion"); }
}

class Lettuce extends Veggies
{
    Lettuce() { super("Lettuce"); }
}

//===============================================================\\
```

Here is just the two array classes

```
class Order
{
    private static List<Items> order = new List<Order>(15);

    public Order() {}
}

class Sandwich
{
    private static ArrayList<Ingredients> ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredients>(20);

    public Sandwich() {}

    public static void addIngredients(Ingredients x) { ingredients.add(x); }


    public String toString()
    {
        String yourOrder = "\n Your order is as follows: \n ";
        for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.size(); i++)
        {
            if (ingredients.get(i) instanceof Bread)
                 { yourOrder += "\nBread type: " + ingredients.get(i); }
            if (ingredients.get(i) instanceof Meat)
                { yourOrder += "\nMeat type: " + ingredients.get(i); }
            if (ingredients.get(i) instanceof Cheese)
                { yourOrder += "\nCheese type: " + ingredients.get(i); }
            if (ingredients.get(i) instanceof Veggies)
                { yourOrder += "\nVeggie type: " + ingredients.get(i); }

    }

    return yourOrder;
   }
}
```

Im not even sure if thats the best way to go about declare the array for the order class. But I would like to store the sandwich arrays in the order class to later print out and add up prices and what not.

Comment: Iv placed all the classes under one file to make it easier to post I understand this is bad practice.

Comment: I don't think we need to know about the Ingredients, Meat, Bread, Cheese, etc. classes to answer your question. Could you simply post the array of Sandwiches and the Array of Orders?

Comment: Personally I would have an `Item` class which `Sandwich` extends and have a separate `Orders` class which would have a `List` of `Items` which are your orders. Then all your logic relating to total order cost etc belongs in the `Orders` class

Comment: yeah I can post that section separately I know some people like to just copy and paste the whole code makes it easier to work with

Comment: Not too clear what you are looking for. Where in your code would you like to pass around this data? Generally you can just assign one array to another location. Common practice in java is to use a "setter" method on the order class to "set" the list of sandwiches associated with that order. This is all based on many many many assumptions and could be totally wrong though.

Comment: Not answering, but some tips based on my opinions: A `Sandwich` is not a kind of Order (so shouldn't extend Order), it is an _Item_ in an Order. A _Drink_ could also be an Item. An `Order` object should not have a list of Orders, it should have a list of _Items_, and declare it as a generic List ... `List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>()` ... an Order is a list of Items, one Item can be a Sandwich, which has a list of Ingredients. Then you don't have to worry about how to "pass" an array to another array (you pass things to methods, you don't "pass" things to an array)

Comment: @JavaDevil that is basically exactly the thing I would like to do. Now are you saying have a: class List extends Sandwich or: Sandwich extends List. I think I will rename the ingredients array to subOrder and store everything in it including sandwich size, drink, chips. It will be easier to just extend and stack all that to the already established ingredients super class

Comment: @StephenP I like this logic. This makes a lot of sense because a person may order 2 sandwiches but only one drink! So have the sandwich class create a sandwich(item) and pass that item to the order. This is good. How would I go about passing the items? Through getters and setters?

Comment: @RickySchiebner you're going to (somewhere) do `sub = new Sandwich()` and add things to the sandwich right? Then somewhere you have `Order order = new Order()` and eventually you `order.add(sub);`

Comment: Re: your comment responding to JavaDevil — a Sandwich is not a List and a List is not a Sandwich. You just want a List that contains Sandwiches (and other kinds of things in your Order). Use `extends` when _Something_ **is-a** _SomethingElse_, like _Drink_ **is-an** _Item_.

Comment: @RickySchiebner Thats not the case, what Stephen P says is what I was getting at. `Orders` would be a separate class as it is not a `Sandwich`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new class called Orders, or OrdersList or something. The OrdersList class will contain multiple of the Order class.

Comment: To make this clearer--remove the concept of "Array" or even Collection from everything.  You might have an object that contains orders, you might have an object that contains sandwiches.  You can pass one object to another--everything else (array/collection manipulation) happens internal to the object.

Comment: If you're processing Orders as they come in, add them to a `java.util.Queue`, then `remove()` or `poll()` the queue to get the next thing to process. And you don't need a special class, just a variable with a proper name. `Queue<Order> orderQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();` for example.

Comment: I don't have extensive knowledge of java yet so Im trying to stick with the basics. This program will simple open with a window a person can select a sandwich press ok a sandwich summery will be displayed then they can choose to make another when they are done they will receive a summery of total cost and that is it.

Comment: @RickySchiebner Is this not simple?